# System freeze on “setting up alsa”

Tags: debian, drivers, startup, alsa

I use Debian wheezy and I boot the computer and get stuck in the line: `[....] setting up alsa ....`

It freezes, it only responds to "REUSIB" ([Emergency Reboot With Magic SysRq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses)), but it is unusable as OS.
I have tried booting in rescue mode and is the same result, get stuck.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is REUSIB?

Comment: @Anthon More often known as REISUB. This means pressing `Alt+SysRq+U` then `Alt+SysRq+B`, with other letters in the sequence that don't do anything useful.

Comment: Can you boot to a busybox shell?  You need to execute `service alsa stop`, then boot, fix alsa, restart the service, and reboot.

Comment: You may also be able to remove the initrd line and boot to 640 x 480 but I won't gaurantee it, as the system may not be able to find `/` with no ramdisk.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am trying to boot `antiX-1.3.2 386` on an old computer. The system freezes right before or after printing `Setting up alsa`. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

To skip the "Setting up ALSA" freezing, press "Ctrl" and the key upper "Tab".

The system boots. Then as root do:

```
apt-get purge pulseaudio*
```

Best regards!

Comment: The question says that the system freezes on boot and is “unusable as OS”. How do you propose that the OP get to a shell prompt?

Comment: In the first line of my answer I indicated how to skip the system boot freezing.